# Setting limited discoverble mode in BLE on android development

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to set limited discoverable mode in bluetooth low energy on android development?

Answer (score 0):

Limited discoverable mode has specific flags in the advertisement data.

But the only types you can change are listed here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html. Flags is not one of them, so you can't.

Comment: So it will be always general discoverable??